# Navigation drawer is under the video

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have the following implementation where user can able to watch video. I have navigation drawer where user can able to navigate to the following Fragment - **TutorialFragment**.

Video automatically starts playing and I want to navigate to other fragment, and I click on navigation drawer icon to launch navigation menu items.

It works but it stay under the video where user cannot able to click.

**TutorialFragment.cs**

```
VideoView videoView;
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
MediaController mediaController;
public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
   var ignored = base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
   var view = this.BindingInflate(Resource.Layout.TutorialView, null); 
   var toolbar = view.FindViewById<Toolbar>(Resource.Id.tutorial_toolbar);

   ((MainView)Activity).SetSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    toolbar.SetNavigationIcon(Resource.Drawable.ic_menu_black_24dp);
    toolbar.Title = "Tutorial";
    toolbar.InflateMenu(Resource.Menu.toolbar_menu);

    videoView = view.FindViewById<VideoView>(Resource.Id.myVideo);
    videoView.Prepared += OnVideoPlayerPrepared;
    mediaController = new MediaController(this.Activity, true);             

   return view;
}

private void StartVideo()
{
    mediaController.SetAnchorView(videoView);
    mediaController.SetMediaPlayer(videoView);
    String fileName = "android.resource://" + this.Activity.BaseContext.PackageName + "/raw/test";
    videoView.SetVideoURI(Uri.Parse(fileName));
    videoView.Start();
}

void OnVideoPlayerPrepared(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  mediaController.Show(2000);
}

public override void OnStart()
{
   base.OnStart();
   StartVideo();
   videoView.SetOnPreparedListener(this);
   videoView.Touch += (sender, e) =>
   {
      if (!(e.Event.Action == MotionEventActions.Down))
          return;
      if (!mediaController.IsShown)
           mediaController.Show();
      else
           mediaController.Hide();
     };

    videoView.Completion += (sender, e) => {
            //base.OnBackPressed();
    };
}

public override void OnStop()
{
  base.OnStop();
  videoView.Prepared -= OnVideoPlayerPrepared;
}
```

Comment: "It works but it stay under the video where user cannot able to click.". Can you please explain this? I cannot understand, I created a demo, seems works fine.

Comment: When I click on drawer icon which is on the action bar, it triggers(opens) the navigation drawer, however, it comes under the `videoviews` where user cannot able to choose any items from the navigation drawer.

Comment: Navigation drawer comes under the video.